# How can I send data to the user without getting the request from the client computer in php

Tags: php, paypal

Consider the user does login operation successfully and the result in the `login.php` file I create a session variable as the `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;`. Now I want send some data to the user that is `login`. For example the user after the `login` clicks the purchase button and goes to the payment gateway page. When the user pays successfully I should redirect him to another page and send some data to him.

What is certain, the user after requesting  to the payment gateway and payment operation, he does not request to my server. But I want send some data to the user after payment operation. But the problem is that the user does not have a new request to my server and my question is, how can I send some data to the user without request operation from that user?

Comment: Use Ajax to make the user continue to make a request.

Comment: I agree with @kainaw

Comment: the paypal  can be configures to be redirected to YOUR thanks page or you can use curl to query PAYPAL API about payment  so you will be able too know about payment status